# canvas in Iframe not resized and redrawn in Firefox

Tags: javascript, iframe, canvas, resize

I have a wysiwyg Iframe that I create with option designermode = "on". 
In it, I , among others, insert a canvas that in its turn draws and resizes based on keyboard input when it has focus.

All works well in Chrome and Safari, but in Firefox, the canvas does not resize. 
Does anybody have an idea why this it does not work in Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

found it out; I disabled designermode before the canvas change and enabled it afterwards.